# Recording the tapped button with the audio

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am creating an instrument. I want that the record button can record the audio and what was tapped.

But when I tap the record button, it only record the audio. I want to record the audio and what was tapped by the user.

Here it my code for record.

```
public void startRecord() throws Exception
{
    record = new MediaRecorder();
    record.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    record.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    record.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    record.setOutputFile(FILE);

    record.prepare();
    record.start();

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate how do you want to record the button which was tapped? Do you want to save the recording by text/title of the button or to append/prepend the voice of which button was clicked?