# Filename of recorded audio

Tags: android, android-file

I can record the audio. But I want the filename is the current date and time.

Here is my code:

```
FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        FILE = FILE + File.separator + "Audio/" +  System.currentTimeMillis() + ".wav";
        System.out.println("Audio path:" + FILE);
```

Comment: Same question as [Recording the tapped button with the audio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694903/recording-the-tapped-button-with-the-audio) but you did not give enough details there. Please edit/update questions instead of asking again. It creates noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date now = new Date();
String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
FILE = FILE + File.separator + "Audio/" +  strDate + ".wav";
System.out.println("Audio path:" + FILE);
```

You can modify the format as you wish.

Comment: Is it important to have System.out.println("Audio path:" + FILE); ?

Comment: I used it to my project. I got a apk file but when a click the save button, the apps crash.

Comment: It is not important to print the filename, you used it, so I. Can you post the crash report from logcat.